# Is it possible to display the result of complex query in SSRS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, t-sql, reporting-services, reporting

I'm new in SSRS and I want to know if it's possible to display a result of a complex query (which run perfectly on SSMS) in my report?

The problem is that I have an `Over` statement in my Query:

```
LEAD(Flow.MeasurementDate) OVER (Partition by 
  ComponentId, NominationCycle, LocationType, Frequency, FlowTypeId, UnitofMeasurement 
ORDER BY MeasurementDate) nextMeasurement, 
MAX(Flow.MeasurementDate) OVER (PARTITION BY 
  ComponentId, NominationCycle, LocationType, Frequency, FlowTypeId, UnitofMeasurement
) maxMeasurement
```

The error message is:

> The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported.

If it's possible please give me few steps to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Over` construct is not supported by the SSRS query designer but the report should still work when the SQL is sent to Sql Server for processing.

If it doesn't, check that your database isn't running in a compatibility level where the `Over` construct is unsupported (80 or earlier).

If all else fails, an alternative is to put your query in a stored procedure and call that from SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

That's just what SSRS is used for in general.
The steps are the same, no matter if it's a simple or complex query.

You use your query to fill a dataset and display this in a table on your report.
What you need is just a basic SSRS tutorial as it can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167305.aspx

Comment: the problem is that I have Over statement in my Query:  LEAD(Flow.MeasurementDate) OVER ( Partition by ComponentId, NominationCycle, LocationType, Frequency, FlowTypeId, UnitofMeasurement ORDER BY  MeasurementDate) nextMeasurement,
  MAX(Flow.MeasurementDate) OVER (PARTITION BY ComponentId, NominationCycle, LocationType, Frequency, FlowTypeId, UnitofMeasurement ) maxMeasurement ... the error message is : The OVER SQL construct or statement is not supported.